# How to transform a CSV matrix to a HTML table via XSLT 1.0?

Tags: csv, xslt-1.0

The XML matrix with csv rows

```
<matrix ROWS="3" COLS="4">
   <row>"1,2,3,4"</row>
   <row>"5,6,7,8"</row>  
   <row>"9,10,11,12"</row>  
</matrix>
```

is to be transformed with XSLT 1.0 without extensions into a HTML table

```
<table>
   <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
   <tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
</table>
```

The number of rows and columns (ROWS, COLS) are variable.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/matrix">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <tr>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring(., 2, string-length(.) - 2)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It took me a while to note that I have to change the method="xml" to method="html" to see the expected result in Firefox. But your implementation is very clear. Thank you.